# AWS CDK how to create an API Gateway backed by Lambda from OpenApi spec?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I want to use AWS CDK to define an API Gateway and a lambda that the APIG will proxy to.

The OpenAPI spec supports a `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` custom extension to the Swagger spec (detailed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html)), for which an invocation URL of the lambda is required. If the lambda is defined in the same stack as the API, I don't see how to provide this in the OpenAPI spec. The best I can think of would be to define one stack with the lambda in, then get the output from this and run `sed` to do a find-and-replace in the OpenAPI spec to insert the uri, then create a second stack with this modified OpenAPI spec.

Example:

```
  /items:
    post:
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:123456789012:function:MyStack-SingletonLambda4677ac3018fa48679f6-B1OYQ50UIVWJ/invocations"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        type: "aws_proxy"
```

Q1. This seems like a chicken-and-egg problem, is the above the only way to do this?

I tried to use the [`defaultIntegration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.SpecRestApi.html#defaultintegration-span-class-api-icon-api-icon-experimental-title-this-api-element-is-experimental-it-may-change-without-notice-span) property of the [SpecRestApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.SpecRestApi.html) CDK construct.  The documentation states:

> An integration to use as a default for all methods created within this
>   API unless an integration is specified.

This seems like a should be able to define a default integration using a lambda defined in the CDK spec and therefore have all methods use this integration, without needing to know the uri of the lambda in advance.

Thus I tried this:

```
SingletonFunction myLambda = ...

SpecRestApi openapiRestApi = SpecRestApi.Builder.create(this, "MyApi")
                        .restApiName("MyApi")
                        .apiDefinition(ApiDefinition.fromAsset("openapi.yaml"))
                        .defaultIntegration(LambdaIntegration.Builder.create(myLambda)
                                    .proxy(false)
                                    .build())
                        .deploy(true)
                        .build();
```

The OpenAPI spec defined in `openapi.yaml` does not include a `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` stanza; it just has a single GET method defined within a standard OpenApi 3 specification.

However, when I try to deploy this, I get an error:

```
No integration defined for method (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 56113150-1460-4ed2-93b9-a12618864582)
```

This seems like a bug, so I filed one [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/8347).

Q2. How do I define an API Gateway and Lambda using CDK and wire the two together via an OpenAPI spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what I'm after is tracked by [this CDK issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1461).  In the meantime, I was guided by the comment on that issue [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1461#issuecomment-589259780) and came up with a workaround.

I used https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java to parse my OpenAPI spec file and replace template values in it that referenced the invocation ARN of the API gateway (that itself references the Lambda ARN).

```
Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
variables.put("restapi-lambda", String.format("arn:aws:apigateway:%s:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/%s/invocations", props.getEnv().getRegion(), myLambda.getFunctionArn()));

Writer writer = new StringWriter();
MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();

Object openapiSpecAsObject;
try (Reader reader = new FileReader(new File("myapi.yaml"))) {
    Mustache mustache = mf.compile(reader, "OAS");
    mustache.execute(writer, scopes);
    writer.flush();

    ObjectMapper yamlMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    openapiSpecAsObject = yamlMapper.readValue(writer.toString(), Object.class);

}

SpecRestApi openapiRestApi = SpecRestApi.Builder.create(this, "MyRestApi")
                                                .restApiName("MyRestApi")
                                                .apiDefinition(ApiDefinition.fromInline(openapiSpecAsObject))
                                                .deploy(true)
                                                .build();
```

Note that `props` is a variable that refers to the `Stack` props and `myLambda` is a reference to a `SingletonFunction`.

My OpenAPI spec looks like this (header and model sections removed):

```
paths:
  /items:
    get:
      summary: List all items.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ItemList'
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: "{{restapi-lambda}}"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        type: "aws_proxy"
```

Also note that when I granted API Gateway permissions to invoke the lambda like this:

```
myLambda.grantInvoke(ServicePrincipal.Builder.create("apigateway.amazonaws.com")
                                              .build());
```

I still get a 500 error and in the logs I can see an "Invalid permissions on Lambda function" error message. If I add permissions to the Lambda, like this:

```
myLambda.addPermission("PermitAPIGInvocation", Permission.builder()
                                  .action("lambda:InvokeFunction")
                                  .principal(ServicePrincipal.Builder.create("apigateway.amazonaws.com")
                                     .build())
                                  .sourceArn(openapiRestApi.arnForExecuteApi())
                                  .build());
```

then I currently need to redeploy the API before the permissions take effect. I'm still working through how to avoid this.

Comment: but the arn of the lambda is only available during deployment right?

Answer (score 13):

There is an existing workaround. Here is how:

Your OpenAPI file has to look like this:

```
openapi: "3.0.1"
info:
  title: "The Super API"
  description: "API to do super things"
  version: "2019-09-09T12:56:55Z"

servers:
- url: ""
  variables:
    basePath:
      default:
        Fn::Sub: ${ApiStage}

paths:
  /path/subpath:
    get:
      parameters:
      - name: "Password"
        in: "header"
        schema:
          type: "string"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/UserConfigResponseModel"
      security:
      - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: 
          Fn::Sub: "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${MySuperLambda.Arn}/invocations"
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{blablabla}"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        type: "aws"
```

As you can see, this OpenAPI template refers to **ApiStage**, **AWS::Region** and **MySuperLambda.Arn**.

The associated cdk file contains the following:

```
// To pass external string, nothing better than this hacky solution: 
const ApiStage = new CfnParameter(this, 'ApiStage',{type: 'String', default: props.ApiStage})
ApiStage.overrideLogicalId('ApiStage')
```

Here the **ApiStage** is used in props. It allows me to pass it to the cdk app with an environment variable during the CI for example.

```
const MySuperLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'MySuperLambda', {
    functionName: "MySuperLambda",
    description: "Hello world",
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
    code: lambda.Code.asset(lambda_asset),
    handler: "MySuperLambda.lambda_handler",
    timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
    memorySize: 128,
    role: MySuperLambdaRole
  });

  const forceLambdaId = MySuperLambda.node.defaultChild as lambda.CfnFunction
  forceLambdaId.overrideLogicalId('MySuperLambda')
```

Here, as previously, I'm forcing CDK to override the logical ids so that I know the id before deployment. Otherwise, cdk adds a suffix to the logical ids.

```
const asset = new Asset(this, 'SampleAsset', {
    path: './api-gateway-definitions/SuperAPI.yml',
  });
```

This allows me to upload the OpenAPI file directly on to the cdk bucket (no need to create a new one, this is amazing).

```
const data = Fn.transform('AWS::Include', {'Location': asset.s3ObjectUrl})
```

This is part of Cloudformation magic. This is where Fn::Sub and Fn::GetAtt are interpreted. I could not manage to make it work with !Ref function.

```
const SuperApiDefinition = apigateway.AssetApiDefinition.fromInline(data)
```

Create an api definition from the previously read file.

```
  const sftpApiGateway = new apigateway.SpecRestApi(this, 'superAPI', {
    apiDefinition: SuperApiDefinition,
    deploy: false
  })
```

Finally, create the SpecRestApi.
Run and magic, this is working. You may still encounter 400 errors, probably because of uncorrect format in your OpenAPI file (and don't use !Ref).

Would I recommand this?
Meh.
This is pretty much a workaround. It is really useful if you want to use the OpenAPI format with dynamic variables, within your CI. Without much effort, you can deploy in dev and prod, just by switching 1 environment variable.

However, this feels really hacky and does not seem to fit in CDK philosophy. This is what I'm currently using for deployment but this will probably change in the future. I believe a real templating solution could have a better fit here, but right now, I don't really thought about it.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a solution which is a bit simpler than the other answers here as it does not require stage variables or multiple deploys.

First, set the `uri` of the `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` to a variable like `${API_LAMBDA_ARN}` and use the same `type` and `httpMethod` as in this example:

```json
[...]
  "paths": {
    "/pets": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "List all pets",
        "responses": {
          [...]
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "uri": "${API_LAMBDA_ARN}",
          "type": "AWS_PROXY",
          "httpMethod": "POST",
        }
      }
    }
  },
[...]
```

Then, you can use this construct (or an equivalent TypeScript implementation) to replace the variable during build time and create an API Gateway Http API based on the OpenAPI Document:

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_iam as iam,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_apigatewayv2 as apigateway
)


class OpenApiLambdaStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(
        self, scope: core.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # function that handles api request(s)
        api_lambda = _lambda.Function([...])

        # read openapi document
        with open("openapi.json", "r") as json_file:
            content = json_file.read()
        # replace the variable by the lambda functions arn
        content = content.replace("${API_LAMBDA_ARN}", api_lambda.function_arn)
        openapi = json.loads(content)

        # create apigateway
        http_api = apigateway.HttpApi(self, "OpenApiLambdaGateway")
        # use escape hatches to import OpenAPI Document
        # see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html
        http_api_cfn: apigateway.CfnApi = http_api.node.default_child
        http_api_cfn.add_property_override("Body", openapi)
        http_api_cfn.add_property_deletion_override("Name")
        http_api_cfn.add_property_deletion_override("ProtocolType")
        # let it fail on warnings to be sure everything went right
        http_api_cfn.add_property_override("FailOnWarnings", True)

        # construct arn of createad api gateway (to grant permission)
        http_api_arn = (
            f"arn:{self.partition}:execute-api:"
            f"{http_api.env.region}:{http_api.env.account}:"
            f"{http_api.http_api_id}/*/*/*"
        )

        # grant apigateway permission to invoke api lambda function
        api_lambda.add_permission(
            f"Invoke By {http_api.node.id} Permission",
            principal=iam.ServicePrincipal("apigateway.amazonaws.com"),
            action="lambda:InvokeFunction",
            source_arn=http_api_arn,
        )
        
        # output api gateway url
        core.CfnOutput(self, "HttpApiUrl", value=http_api.url)
```

Python users might also be interested in the [openapigateway](https://github.com/suud/cdk-openapigateway) construct I've published to make this  process even more straight-forward. It supports JSON and YAML.

Comment: but the arn of the lambda is only available during deployment right?

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented the same by using just Python and CDK as following

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_apigateway as apig,
    aws_lambda,
    Stack,
    BundlingOptions,
    aws_s3_assets as s3_assets,
    Fn
)
from constructs import Construct

from os import path

import json

class ApigLambdaStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        my_lambda_fn = aws_lambda.Function(self, 'MyFunction',
            runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
            handler='main.handler',            
            code=aws_lambda.Code.from_asset(path.join(path.dirname('.'), 'my_lambda_fn'),
                bundling=BundlingOptions(
                    image=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9.bundling_image,
                        command=['bash', '-c', 'pip install -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output && cp -au . /asset-output'
                    ]
                )
            )
        )

        swagger_file = None
        with open('./swagger.json') as f:
            swagger_file = f.read()

        swagger_file = swagger_file.replace("${LAMBDA_ARN}", my_lambda_fn.function_arn)                                    

        my_apig = apig.SpecRestApi(self, 'my-awesome-apis', api_definition=apig.ApiDefinition.from_inline(json.loads(swagger_file)))
```

and in my swagger.json file I've

```
{
    "openapi" : "3.0.1",
    "info" : {
      "title" : "demo",
      "version" : "2023-01-26T11:14:54Z"
    },
    "servers" : [ {
      "url" : "https://12345abc.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/{basePath}",
      "variables" : {
        "basePath" : {
          "default" : "/v1"
        }
      }
    } ],
    "paths" : {
      "/" : {
        "post" : {
          "responses" : {
            "200" : {
              "description" : "200 response",
              "content" : {
                "application/json" : {
                  "schema" : {
                    "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/Empty"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "x-amazon-apigateway-integration" : {
            "type" : "aws_proxy",
            "uri" : "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LAMBDA_ARN}/invocations",
            "httpMethod" : "POST",
            "responses" : {
              "default" : {
                "statusCode" : "200"
              }
            },
            "passthroughBehavior" : "when_no_match",
            "contentHandling" : "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "components" : {
      "schemas" : {
        "Empty" : {
          "title" : "Empty Schema",
          "type" : "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

NB To be clear LAMBDA_ARN is a placeholder that will be replaced by CloudFormation and not by Python! Python doesn't know anything about the Lambda ARN...

Hope this helps!