# Template openapi template for aws_apigateway.SpecRestApi from another stack

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

Its a pretty common pattern when using API GW openapi to reference logical ids from the same stack to create a template where items are substituted.  While some consider it a bit hacky it works well in my opinion for being able to leverage 1 stop development and deployments with openapi.  Reference to this is at [AWS CDK how to create an API Gateway backed by Lambda from OpenApi spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62179893/aws-cdk-how-to-create-an-api-gateway-backed-by-lambda-from-openapi-spec).

Looking for best practices as if there is a way to reference an item in another stack when creating the openapi template.

Stack 1 (a shared s3 bucket)
Stack 2 take in param to s3 as shown below (which generates an export in the cloud formation templates)

```
interface Stack2Props extends CommonStackProps {
    bucket_1: aws_s3.Bucket
}

export class Stack2 extends Stack {


    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: Stack2Props) {
        super(scope, id, props);
....
}
```

The best i could figure to do was in the stack 1 to export a well known from stack 1 variable then reference it in stack2 in the template:

```
        // export for cross-stack reference in the template
        new CfnOutput(this, 'BucketRef', {
            value: bucket.bucketName,
            description: 'The bucket name of the bucket',
            exportName: 'MyBucket',
        });
```

```
        uri:
          Fn::Sub:
            - 'arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:s3:path/${MyBucket}/{path}'
            - MyBucket:
                Fn::ImportValue: MyBucket
```

Don't know if there is a better way here to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using AWS CDK - a library for a high-level language you can avoid using CloudFormation methods like Fn::Sub and replace the values in your case in Typescript by passing a dictionary to something like a [brackets parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/curly-bracket-parser)

Here is a simple standalone solution

```
private compileOpenApi(apiDefinition: string, dictionary: { [key: string]: string }): string {
        let compiledDefinition = apiDefinition;

        Object.entries(dictionary).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            compiledDefinition = compiledDefinition.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), value);
        });

        return compiledDefinition;
    }
```

And pass the values you want to replace like

```
new apigateway.SpecRestApi(
    this, `MySpecRestApi`, {
        apiDefinition: apigateway.ApiDefinition.fromInline(
            JSON.parse(this.compileOpenApi(fs.readFileSync(props.openApiFilePath).toString(), {
                '{{MyBucketArn}}': props.myBucketArn,
                '{{MyBucketPath}}': props.myBucketPath,
        }))),
    }
```